# Register Answers given by a User in a Test

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 SQL tables that define a test:

```
create table Tests ( 
  TestId int identity not null primary key
)

create table TestsQuestions (
  QuestionId int foreign key references Questions(QuestionId),
  TestId int foreign key references Tests(TestId),
    constraint PK primary key clustered (TestId, QuestionId)
)

create table Questions (
  QuestionId int identity not null primary key
)

create table Answers (
  AnswerId int identity not null primary key,
  QuestionId int not null foreign key references Questions(QuestionId),
  IsCorrectAnswer bit not null
)
```

And a Users table:

```
create table Users ( 
  UserId int identity not null primary key
)
```

To register which Tests a User has done I am using:

```
create table UsersTests (
  UserId int foreign key references Users(UserId),
  TestId int foreign key references Tests(TestId),
    constraint PK primary key clustered (UserId, TestId)
)
```

But I also need to register which Answers a User gave in each question.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a simple "put all keys into one table" situation, where you'll have to inner join in a view to get more complex data out of it

```
 Create Table UsersTestsQuestionsAnswers( 
  UserId int NOT NULL foreign key references UsersTests(UserId),
  TestID int NOT NULL foreign key references UsersTests(TestId),
  AnswerID int NOT NULL foreign key references Answers(AnswerId) 
  constraint PK primary key clustered (UserId, TestId, AnswerID) 
)
```

You should be able to inner join yourself out of that situation